# Is there a way I can automate several which.max functions on a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

Say I have a dataframe of:

```
 DF <- data.frame(V1=c(2,8,1),V2=c(7,3,5),V3=c(9,6,4))
>DF
   V1 V2 V3
1  2  7  9
2  8  3  6
3  1  5  4
```

I know you can return the rowname of the highest value for a single column by using:

```
which.max(DF[,1])
```

but would it be possible to use which match the return the rowname of the highest value in each column without manually typing a `which.max` for each column in the dataframe?

Comment: If your data is entirely numeric, you should probably use a matrix, in which case `max.col(t(DF))` is an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a loop

```
sapply(DF, which.max)
```

Comment: or a hidden loop `Vectorize(which.max)(DF)`